# Understanding partial derivative of logistic regression cost function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, logistic-regression

I'm following along in Andrew Ng's great lecture series on machine learning, and he presents the following as the cost function for a logistic regression model [[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_xiwjEdAC4&feature=youtu.be&t=0m43s)]:

$$L(a,y) = -(y \log(a) + (1 - y) \log(1 - a)) $$

He then builds a little math graph, or series of equations, that can be used as helpers for computing the partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to various variables [[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_xiwjEdAC4&feature=youtu.be&t=0m43s)]:

$$ z = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + b $$
$$ \hat{y} = a = \sigma(z) $$

Next he says that the following represents the derivative of $L$ wrt $a$ [[link](https://youtu.be/z_xiwjEdAC4?t=2m48s)]:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = -\frac{y}{a} + \frac{1-y}{1-a} $$

Unfortunately, he doesn't give any clues as to how this can be derived. Does anyone here know how to derive this partial derivative given the equations above? I'd be very grateful for any insights others can offer on this question!

Comment: Hmmm... did you realize that the "answer" below does not apply to your setting?

Comment: @Did no I didn't--can you help me see why it doesn't apply?

Comment: Because $L(a,y)$ in your question and $L(a,y)$ in this "answer" are not the same.

Comment: @Did I don't follow--I take them both to be function arguments but am learning. Can I ask you for more details?

Comment: Yours is $-(\ldots+\ldots)$, the other one is $-\ldots+\ldots$.

Comment: Typo in your comment as well...

Comment: ?? Simply correct the faulty sign and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your equation is

$$L(a,y)=-\left(y\log(a)+(1-y)\log(1-a)\right)$$

we get

$$\frac{\partial L(a,y)}{\partial a}=-\left(\frac{y}{a}+\frac{1-y}{1-a}\cdot (-1)\right)$$

which simplifies to

$$-\frac{y}{a} + \frac{1-y}{1-a}$$

since

$$(\log(a))'=\frac{1}{a}$$

and

$$(\log(1-a))'=\frac{1}{1-a}\cdot (-1)$$

using the chain rule

Comment: Thanks very much @Dr.SonhardGraubner this is very helpful. My only remaining doubt is the `log(1-a)'` term -- could I ask how you applied the chain rule in this case?

Comment: since $$(1-a)'=-1$$

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: Ah yes, because 1' = 0, (a^1)' = 1, and 0 - 1 = -1. Thanks very much!

Comment: all the best in the year 2018!

Comment: I've got lots of calculus to learn before then :)

Comment: and if there is a Problem we will solve this